# How to exclude unwanted folders content to be shown when I execute 'git status' command

Tags: git, gitignore, git-status

I'm trying to avoid showing unwanted folder's content (ex:- .settings, .metadata etc ) when i execute `git status` command.

I modified .gitignore file after adding the folder names to it but still I'm getting all these files when I execute git status.

Answer (score 33):

Run this from the git project directory, where `dir` is directory you want to exclude.

```
git status . -- ':!dir'
```

For your example if want to exclude multiple directories (e.g. `settings` and `metadata`).

```
git status . -- ':!settings' ':!metadata'
```

Comment: This is currently the best option I have used in 2021

Comment: This solution best answers the question as the scope of the question was about git. `grep -v` is an option but it is a more complicated solution. This simpler solution should be preferred.

Comment: ignore dir:  `git status -s --  ":(exclude)*wwwroot*" `

Answer (score 5):

`.gitignore` works only on untracked files.

To stop tracking an already tracked file in git, type

```
git rm --cached <file>
git rm -r --cached <folder>
```

and then commit the change

```
git commit -m "Stop tracking some files"
```

Comment: Actually, its not working even for untracked files. Please suggest me if I've to do any other changes for untracked files.

Comment: @rohit89 Does `git rm --cached <file>` actually delete files on the disk?

Comment: @John No. It only stops git from tracking those files.

Answer (score 5):

You can just remove them with `grep -v` if you're only interested not seeing them.

Answer (score 3):

I will not echo what others have said about the usage of `.gitignore` because I believe they have covered it, but I like your question about omitting results from `git status`.

I have found **no way to omit specific directories** other than specifying the sub-directory for which you want status, i.e. `git status <subdirectory>`, where the current directory is the default.

This is insufficient in some cases depending on how a project is organized. For example, in Go when using `dep`, there is a `vendor` directory that gets checked in and it would be desirable to exclude only that, but the best I can do is to `git status` on a series of sub-directories (not fun). Same goes for `git diff`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the git glossary [`pathspec`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-exclude), if you want a quick peek on the changes made to all the folder other than `**/settings/`, here is how

```
git status ':(exclude,top)**/settings/*' ./
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a generic solution to this problem using only git status command. However, for the exclusive scenario of developing on a Golang project where you want to exclude the /vendor, I typically append '| grep -v vendor' to the git status.

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` and related facilities only work on untracked files. As soon as a file is tracked (added to Git) you can put it inside `.gitignore`, but it will have no effect at all. There is no good way to handle this, besides removing those files from the repository and having them not checked in.

You might read about [`--assume-unchanged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---no-assume-unchanged), but this is a very dangerous option. You can tell Git to assume a file is unchanged, even though you have changes in it. But that also means that the security mechanisms that make sure you don't loose uncommitted changes do not work on those files. So if you have a changed `.settings` and then switch to a branch where the checked in `.settings` file is different than on the branch you are currently on, the file will be overwritten with the new branch's state and your local changes are lost.

Comment: What `--assume-unchanged`?  Do you mean `git status --assume-unchanged`？

Comment: `git-status` doe not have `--assume-unchanged` @John. What I meant is [git update-index --assume-unchanged ...](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---no-assume-unchanged)