# How to exclude some directories from output of git status without having to modify the working tree (e.g. _not_ modifying .gitignore)

Tags: git

In my working tree there's a directory with several modified files that I temporarily would like to *not* see when I do `git status`. But this should ideally be done without modifying the "state" of my working tree.  How could I do this?

I looked at `man git-status` but couldn't see an option to exclude a specific directory.

Some workarounds:

- Use `git status | grep -v dir-to-exclude`, but then I lose the pretty colours.
- Specify all the other directories and files as arguments to git status, i.e. `git status dir-1 dir-2 dir-3 file-1 file-2`
- Use `git stash` to temporarily store modifications in `dir-to-exclude/`, but that modifies my state
- Temporarily add `dir-to-exclude/` to `.gitignore`, but that modifies the state of my working tree and I have remember to revert the change. It also does not work for *modified* version controlled files.
- Use some other command than `git status`, if one exists???

If there's no ready made option for `git status`, then somehow using `grep` without losing the pretty colours is perhaps what I should be using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make Git ignore files without using .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653454/how-do-you-make-git-ignore-files-without-using-gitignore)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ignore+file+without+.gitignore

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude unwanted folders content to be shown when I execute 'git status' command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701677/how-to-exclude-unwanted-folders-content-to-be-shown-when-i-execute-git-status)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 git -c color.ui=always status | grep -v <dir-to-exclude>
```

See **Colors in Git** section [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

> Git fully supports colored terminal output, which greatly aids in
>   visually parsing command output quickly and easily. A number of
>   options can help you set the coloring to your preference.
>
> **color.ui**
>
> Git automatically colors most of its output, but there’s a
>   master switch if you don’t like this behavior.
>
> You can also set it to always to ignore the difference between
>   terminals and pipes.

Comment: This works well for me, especially as I was already using ```alias gst='git status'```, which I'm now modifying to ```alias gst='git -c color.ui=always status' ```. Thus, the following works nicely now: ```gst | grep -v <dir-to-exclude>```.   Note: The "gst" is just my own acronym for "git status" as it's quick to type.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [How to exclude unwanted folders content to be shown when I execute 'git status' command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701677/how-to-exclude-unwanted-folders-content-to-be-shown-when-i-execute-git-status)

Use `git status . -- ':!dir'` to exclude the `dir` folder when running `git status`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an appropriate use for [`git update-index --skip-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---no-skip-worktree). To quote from [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit),

> Skip-worktree bit can be defined in one (long) sentence: When reading an entry, if it is marked as skip-worktree, then Git pretends its working directory version is up to date and read the index version instead.

In other words, if you set this flag on a file with `git update-index --skip-worktree <filename>`, then Git will ignore the actual contents and metadata of the file on disk and will simply pretend it's unmodified. This only applies for *read* operations; if you run a Git operation that would *write* to the file (e.g. `git checkout` or `git reset`), then Git will give you a warning.

Personally I have this command aliased to `git ignore`, and the opposite version, `git update-index --no-skip-worktree`, aliased to `git unignore`. Of course if you're going to do this, you have to remember that this is entirely unrelated to the mechanism that uses `.gitignore` files, so you might want to choose a different name if there is any chance of confusion.

Comment: For my use case this feels too much like modifying the state, i.e. I have to remember to undo it later.

Comment: Ah, are you looking for something that can be given as an option to `git status`, like for one-time use? In that case, yeah, this is not what you need. I'll leave the answer here in case it benefits other people in similar situations, though.